# How do I upgrade without adding files with WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I'm making MSI's with WiX for our product. The product loads some optional assemblies as modules. This allows us to just drop a dll into the directory and charge a bit more!

Now I want to make a common major upgrade MSI that includes all the possile module assemblies but only upgrades files that exist, and doesnt install missing ones. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally those "drop-in" assemblies should have been installed with another MSI. That way you just need to chain a series of MSIs to do upgrades.

Comment: Idealy I would like to have a common upgrade msi rather than one for each customer... maybe I'm dreaming

Comment: I don't understand your design well enough to suggest alternatives.